# submit form with method GET Automatic

Tags: javascript, php, forms, submit

I want to submit a form with method `GET` like this :

```
search.php?q=Clothing&amp;p=1&amp;per=10
```

When I try this code I just get:

```
search.php?per=10
```

Here is my code :

```
<?php

echo '<div id="filter">';
echo '<form action="search.php?q='.$q.'&p='.$page.'" name="per" method="get">';
echo '<div class="pages_filter"><div class="total_results">About <span>'.$result_count.'</span> results</div>';
echo '<div class="option_results">'.$total_pages.' Pages 
      <select id="resultsPerPage" name="per" onchange="autoSubmit()">';
for ($z = 0 ; $z <= 40 ; $z++){
$z=$z+10;
echo '<option type="submit" ';if ($z==$p){echo ' selected="selected "';} echo ' value="'.$z.'">'.$z.'</option>';
$z=$z-1;
}
echo '</select> Per page.
</form>
</div></div>';
echo '</div>'; /// #filter

?>
```

Javascript code :

```
<script language="JavaScript">
function autoSubmit()
{
     var formObject = document.forms['per'];
     formObject.submit();
}
</script>
```

How can I do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
echo '<form action="search.php" name="per" method="get">';
echo '<input type="hidden" name="q" value="'.$q.'" />';
echo '<input type="hidden" name="p" value="'.$page.'" />';
```